# How to Switch Between View Controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7, xcode5

So, right now, in my Main.storyboard, I have a View Controller we'll call "S B View Controller". I added another view controller, which is called "View Controller". How do I make it so that when a user presses a button, it will go from S B View controller to View Controller? Or, is this not how I'm supposed to to something like this?

Sorry if you don't understand this; just tell me if you don't

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are tons of Stack Overflow questions, online tutorials, and other resources already available for this question. Please research thoroughly before asking a new question on Stack Overflow. Here's a hint though: You need Storyboard segues.

Comment: Please refer the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) and research thoroughly. This is a question asked multiple times before.

Answer (score 1):

What i typically do is this.

Set up a Button in a ViewController and then Control-Drag and it creates a blue flexible arrow and drop it onto the View i want to open when clicked.
[image]

Then a small pop up menu shows up and select Modal.

I then would create another button in the other view in which will return to the original view. For example, the "Done" would dismiss the view after.

Here is the code to Dismiss:

```
   - (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

  }
```

Which will then dismiss the View which is by the way, the second View.

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Lot of tutorials available for storyboard segues, 
Check the following simple tutorials,
[appcoda tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/%22), [raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a SwitchViewController, then two other views, lets call those BlueViewController and YellowViewController.

You could then use the following action when pressing your button:
    - (IBAction)switchViews
    {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.4];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

```
if(!self.yellowViewController.view.superview) {
    if(!self.yellowViewController){
        self.yellowViewController = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Yellow"];
    }
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:NO];
    [self.blueViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.yellowViewController.view atIndex:0];
} else {
    if(!self.blueViewController){
        self.blueViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Blue"];
    }
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:1];
    [self.yellowViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.blueViewController.view atIndex:0];
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Should be pretty self-explanatory. If any questions arise, lets hear.